# Elegant list of conditions in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm making a unit converting function for Python for fun.

This is my code, so far:

```
def UnitConverter(number,*units):
    if units == ("feet","inches"):
        return number*12
    elif units == ("ft","yd"):
        return number/3
```

You probably get the idea of how I'm having this work.

Because I'm obsessive about elegance, good code practice, and overall flow, I want to know what you coders think about this in general, in addition to my main question: **How can I efficiently check for a list of permutations in an `if` statement**?

Example: Is there an efficient way to make this work?

```
def UnitConverter(number,*units):
    if units == (("feet" or "foot" or "ft."),("inches" or "in" or "in.")):
        return number*12
    elif units == ("ft","yd"):
        return number/3
```

If not, is there a way to restructure my program such that someone can enter the three arguments `number`, `unit1`, `unit2` in a way that on the coding end, I can effectively include all alternate spellings of each unit (`feet`,`foot`,`ft`,`etc`)?

I really value everyone's opinion.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you accepting `*units` and then repeatedly implicitly forcing it to be two values, instead of just accepting, say, `fromunit, tounit` as two separate parameters?

Comment: Also, trying to handle the cartesian product of N units with N-1 other units is going to mean a whole lot of code if N is much better than 3. Why not do this in two steps: convert from the `fromunit` to some canonical unit, then convert from the canonical unit to the `tounit`. Then you only need N*2 `if` conditions instead of N**2.

Comment: +1 to abarnert, except make it `from_unit` and `to_unit`

Comment: @abarnert I'm using *units because I originally planned to return as many conversions as the user wanted, a one-to-many conversion.

Comment: @jwarner112: OK, that makes sense… but I'd still write it as `from_unit, *to_units`; it makes it a bit more obvious what the arguments mean. Anyway.

Comment: One more suggestion here: The (BSD or GNU) [units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/) tool does almost exactly what you want, and it comes with a nifty, relatively easy-to-parse data file `units.lib` that can be used to build, e.g., the dictionary used in RemcoGerlich's answer.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks! You've done a lot to help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would pick a standard unit of length, let's say m. Then I would have a single dictionary that gives a factor for each other unit, and convert:

```
conversion_factors = {
    'foot': 0.3048,  # Google search '1 foot in m'
    'yard': 0.9144,
    # etc
}

def unit_convert(number, from_unit='m', to_unit='m'):
    m = number * conversion_factor[from_unit]
    return m / conversion_factor[to_unit]
```

For the synonyms (feet, ft, etc) you could make a second dictionary and lookup the canonical name in that first:

```
conversion_factors = { ... }  # as above

synonyms = {
    'feet': 'foot',
    'ft': 'foot',
    ...
}

def unit_convert(number, from_unit='m', to_unit='m'):
    from_unit = synonyms.get(from_unit, from_unit)
    to_unit = synonyms.get(to_unit, to_unit)
    # etc
```

...or just put them in the `conversion_factors` dictionary multiple times:

```
conversion_factors = {
    'foot': 0.3048,  # Google search '1 foot in m'
    'feet': 0.3048,
    'ft': 0.3048,
    'yard': 0.9144,
    # etc
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I'd write it… but you should add one example of how it solves the problem the OP had in the first place: multiple names for the same unit. Just add `'feet': 0.3048,`.

Answer (score 4):

Use sets.

```
foot_units = {"ft.", "feet", "foot"}
```

Then you can check ownership in the sets.

```
if(units[0] in foot_units):
   ...
```

Beyond this, make a conversion_factor dictionary that goes to a common conversion element. You can then coerce to your final after.

```
inches -> feet -> yards
inches -> feet -> feet
```

RemcoGerlich has a good solution for that step.

Comment: If you want to simplify this, I'd use a single 1D table to convert each unit to/from a single canonical unit, instead of a 2D table, which is going to explode combinatorially (and we all know how messy that can be) just like the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like the following, using the `in` operator which checks for containment:

```
def UnitConverter(number,*units):
    feet = {'feet', 'foot', 'ft.'}
    inches = {'inches', 'in', 'in.'}
    yards = {'yard', 'yd', 'yd.'}
    if units[0] in feet and units[1] in inches:
        return number*12
    elif units[0] in feet and units[1] in yards:
        return number/3
```